# Form get's resent on refresh

Tags: php, mysql, forms, page-refresh

Form get's resent on refresh, I had read about `header("Location:my_page.php")` `unset($_POST)`, but I'm not sure where to place it.

This is our script, it works as need it, but it keeps re-sending on page refresh (Chrome browser alerts over and over), can some one fix the code and explain to my like 2 years old child.

```
<form action='thi_very_same_page.php' method='post'>
Search for Christian Movies <input type='text' name='query' id='text'  />
<input type='submit' name='submit' id='search' value='Search' />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "toor") or die("Error connecting to database: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error());
    $query = $_POST['query'];

    $min_length = 2;
    if (strlen($query) >= $min_length) 
    {
        $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        echo "";

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(lasteditdate, '%m-%d-%Y') AS lasteditdate  FROM movies WHERE (`moviename` LIKE '%" . $query . "%') OR (`year` LIKE '%" . $query . "%')") or die(mysql_error());

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
        {
            while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
                echo "";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "";
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use mysql* use PDO instead.

Comment: I'm new to this whole php scripts, not even know how use this simple one, now that PDO seems to be a whole new story :/

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php and http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

Comment: Your question is not clear try to explain your problem in detail and currently your code echos nothing

Comment: I had edit the main question, added the input form to it, now the issue is: If my college mates, do enter a criteria (movie name), if hit f5, page alerts (The Page you're looking for used information that you entered. Returning to that page migth cause any action took to be repeated, Do you wnat to contine?) ... That is what happens :(

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the form data gets submitted again upon refresh, check this method

http://www.andypemberton.com/engineering/the-post-redirect-get-pattern/

You set your header to   header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');

Data wont be cached, so when page refreshes the form data wont get submitted again!

Comment: Thanks for the link, my english is not that good, need it time to read that whole page, now about the header set to HTTP/1, how  to do it ?, Thanks :*

Comment: you write header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other'); in your code that does the processing of data before redirecting it to the same page

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the `post` method to submit the form values so when ever you tries to refresh the browser asks you whether to send the form information or not it is the default behavior of the browser to tackle the posted information, the alternate solution for your problem is you can use the `get` method like in form attribute `method='get'` what it does it will append all the information of form in the URL which we call the `query string` and in PHP code you are accessing the form values in `$_POST` but when using get method the form values will now appear in the `$_GET` method these methods are called request method and are PHP's global variables, Now when you try to refresh it will not ask you to resend information because the information now resides in the URL

```
<form action='thi_very_same_page.php' method='get'>
Search for Christian Movies <input type='text' name='query' id='text'  />
<input type='submit' name='submit' id='search' value='Search' />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) 
{
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "toor") or die("Error connecting to database: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error());
    $query = $_GET['query'];

    $min_length = 2;
    if (strlen($query) >= $min_length) 
    {
        $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        echo "";

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(lasteditdate, '%m-%d-%Y') AS lasteditdate  FROM movies WHERE (`moviename` LIKE '%" . $query . "%') OR (`year` LIKE '%" . $query . "%')") or die(mysql_error());

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
        {
            while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
                echo "";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "";
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "";
    }
} ?>
```

Hope this is enough to explain you about the form submission one thing I will suggest you to deeply look at below

---

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).